# Using std::accumulate

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I always try to incorporate STL algorithms wherever I can, rather than writing manual loops.  However, I'm having difficulty understanding how `std::accumulate` is generally useful.  Whenever I need to calculate sums or averages, I almost always end up resorting to manual loops, because I have difficulty getting `std::accumulate` to do what I need.

The problem is that I rarely ever have a simple vector of integers that need to be summed.  Usually, I want to sum an array of objects using a particular member variable.  Yes, I know there is a version of `std::accumulate` that takes a BinaryFunction, but the problem I see is that this function needs to take two values of type `T`, where `T` is the type of the *sum*, rather than the type of the *operands*.  I'm having trouble understanding how this is useful.

Consider a case which I assume is pretty common.  I have the following class:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int cost_, int id_) : cost(cost_), id(id_)
    { }

    int cost;
    int id;
};
```

Now, say I want to calculate the sum of an array of `Foo` objects, using `Foo::cost`.

I want to say:

```
std::vector<Foo> vec;
// fill vector with values
int total_cost = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, sum_cost);
```

And `sum_cost` is defined as:

```
int sum_cost(const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2)
{
    return f1.cost + f2.cost;
}
```

The problem is, this doesn't work because `std::accumulate` expects a BinaryFunction which takes in two instances of the *resulting sum type* - which in this case is just `int`.  But how is that useful to me?  If my BinaryFunction takes in two `int`s, I can't specify that I want to sum the `cost` field.

So, why is `std::accumulate` designed this way?  Am I just not seeing something obvious here?

Comment: If your class represents objects that can be accumulated, you can consider adding + and += operators.

Comment: Nitpick: `std::accumulate` expects a BinaryFunction, not a BinaryPredicate. Predicates return a boolean value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're wrong about accumulate operator taking two of the same type.  It does that only if you want to.  The use the operator is specifically `sum = op(sum, *iter)`.  Thus your code:

```
int count = std::accumulate(stuff.begin(), stuff.end(), 0, [](int current_sum, stuff_value_t const& value) { return current_sum + value.member; });
```

If you can't use lambda then of course you use the standard binders or boost::bind.

Comment: He did not tag this `c++0x` so your use of lambda is less than useful.

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  I seem to have gotten bad information from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/ "here"), which reads "Binary operation taking two elements of type T as argument, and returning the result of an accumulation operation."

Comment: @Channel - yep.  That source is erroneous.

Answer (score 4):

use functor:

```
class F { // sum Foos
    F(int init = 0);
    template<class T>
    Foo operator()(const Foo &a, const T &b) const;
    operator int() const;
};

int total_cost = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), F(0), F());
```

notice you can do other things as well:

```
class F { // sum foo values members
    template<class T>
    T operator()(const T &a, const Foo &b) const;
};
int total_cost = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), int(0), F());
```