# How to add all numbers in an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, addition

Instead of typing

```
array[0] + array[1] //.....(and so on)
```

is there a way to add up all the numbers in an array?  The language I'm using would be c++
I want to be able to do it with less typing than I would if I just typed it all out.

Comment: `std::accumulate` does just what it says on the tin, which is one reason to use it over a loop.

Comment: For vectors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/sum-of-elements-in-a-stdvector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
int array[] = {3, 2, 1, 4};
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sum = sum + array[i];
}
std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. their are many answers for this questions are available and are marked as accepted

Answer (score 49):

Here is the idiomatic way of doing this in C++:

```
int a[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
int total = accumulate(begin(a), end(a), 0, plus<int>());
```

Note, this example assumes you have somewhere:

```
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
```

Also see: [accumulate docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) and [accumulate demo](http://ideone.com/GSvItF).

Comment: Worth noting addition is the default.

Comment: Also worth noting that for types other than `int`, the third argument must be a 0 of the right type, e.g. 0.0 when summing up `double`s.

Comment: I don't know why or when this changed, but I had to `#include <numeric>` for this to work. [Cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) confirms this.

Comment: @dasblinkennight - what if my array is an array of pointers to data such as this - slist->items_per_level  = (uint64_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t) * maxLevel);

Comment: @gansub This is explained in [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5158578/335858) with a pretty nice answer.

Comment: It stopped being *idiomatic C++* as soon as it started with `int a[]` haha :D

Answer (score 14):

Say you have an `int array[N]`.

You can simply do:

```
int sum = 0;
for(auto& num : array)
    sum += num;
```

Comment: So much cleaner than accumulate, assuming you have C++11 support, and doesn't require two extra includes.

Comment: And by using short variable names, this golfs better than accumulate (even without taking into account the includes). The only advantage of accumulate is self documentation I guess?

Comment: @Ciro: This isn't the only advantage of accumulate.
If you have `int array[100];` and you sort part of it like this `sort(a, a + n);`,  the solution with accumulate allows me to create one-line beautiful summation: `int revenue = accumulate(a, a + min(m, n), 0);`.
You can look up the code where I used it here: [codeforces.com - Sereja and Coat Rack](http://codeforces.com/contest/368/submission/12620328)

Answer (score 4):

If you use a `valarray`, there is a member function `sum()` for that.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <valarray>     // std::valarray

int main () {
  std::valarray<int> myvalarray(4);
  myvalarray[0] = 0;
  myvalarray[1] = 10;
  myvalarray[2] = 20;
  myvalarray[3] = 30;
  std::cout << "The sum is " << myvalarray.sum() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can see to do this is to use a loop. The bonus is that you can use it on any integer array without rewriting much code at all. I use Java more often, so I hope there aren't too many syntax errors, but something like this should work:

```
int addArray(int[] array, int length){
    int sum=0;
    for(int count=0;count<length;count++){
        sum+=array[count];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: For C++ "int [] array" needs to be "int *array". Otherwise, it works fine. You could add that you are making a function that uses a loop so in the future they can just call addArray()

Comment: @Scooter, The two are equivalent to the compiler in that context.

Comment: @chris Look closer. They are doing it the Java way - "int[] array" - not "int array[]". But yeah, I should have used "int array []" as it is clearer than "int *array".

Comment: @Scooter, Ah, yes, I didn't notice. I actually prefer `int *` myself if I have to pick one for a parameter because it isn't silently replaced with a different type there like `int[]` is; what you see is what you get and then anyone who doesn't know about the transformation won't try to expect `sizeof` to work or anything.

Comment: Up Vote just because of that awesome nick!  ;)

Answer (score 3):

In C++17, one could use fold expressions:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
int sum_impl(Ts&& ...a)
{
    return (a + ...);
}
```

If `sum_impl` had a constant number of parameters, we could have called it like this:

```
std::apply(sum_impl, arr);
```

assuming arr is `std::array<int, N>`. But since it is variadic, it needs a little push with helpers:

```
using namespace std;

template <class Array, size_t... I>
int sum_impl(Array&& a, index_sequence<I...>)
{
        return sum_impl(get<I>(forward<Array>(a))...);
}

template <class Array>
int sum(Array&& a)
{
        return sum_impl(forward<Array>(a),
                        make_index_sequence<tuple_size_v<decay_t<Array>>>{});
}
```

Therefore, assuming these helpers are in place, the code will look something like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
int sum_impl(Ts&& ...a)
{
    return (a + ...);
}

int main()
{
    array<int, 10> arr{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    cout << sum(arr) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use user defined function.

Code Snippet :

```js
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int sum(int arr[], int n)
{
    int sum=0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}


int main()
{
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int n = distance(begin(arr), end(arr));

  int total = sum(arr,n);

  printf("%d", total);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Sum;
for(int& S: List) Sum += S;
```

Comment: Please explain what this is doing, don't just post code

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports c++17, you may use a combination of Parameter pack and fold expression to achieve this. A template parameter pack is a template parameter that accepts zero or more template arguments, and fold reduces the parameter pack over a binary operator. (`+` in this case)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

/* 
 * References:
 *   [1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold
 *   [2] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack
 */


template <typename ...T>
auto sum(T ...args)
{
    return (args + ...);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t ...Is>
auto sum(T t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return sum(t[Is]...);
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> a1 = {1, 4, 3};
    int a2[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 0};

    std::cout << "Sum a1 = " << sum(a1, std::make_index_sequence<a1.size()>{}) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Sum a2 = " << sum(a2, std::make_index_sequence<5>{}) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Adding one more point regarding std::accumulate usage:***

When a **C-style array is passed to a function** then you should explicitly specify the **array** `start` and `end`(one-past-the-end) addresses when you use the `std::accumulate`.

Example:

```
#include <numeric>
void outsideFun(int arr[], int n) {
    int sz = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]; // 1=decays to a ptr to the 1st element of the arr
    // int sum = accumulate(begin(arr), end(arr), 0); // Error:begin/end wouldn't work here
    int sum = accumulate(arr, arr + n, 0);            // 15 (Method 2 Only works!)
    std::cout << sum;
}

int main() {    
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int sz = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];           // 5
    int sum = accumulate(begin(arr), end(arr), 0); // 15 (Method 1 - works)
    int cum = accumulate(arr, arr + sz, 0);        // 15 (Method 2 - works)
    outsideFun(arr, sz);
}
```